# I want to make a word disappear after it performs a CSS animation during a mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, animation, hover, visibility

I am trying to get my code to play an animation (one word falling to the bottom of the page before disappearing), when a mouse hovers over a word in a class div, and after that have it disappear for good.

The CSS 'visibility property' allows me to choose whether the word is visible or not, but when dealing with 'class:hover' like I am, the word comes back when the mouse is not hovering over the word's position. Same with 'display: none';

When JavaScript (document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "hidden";) is applied with the help of onmouseover, the word will disappear without playing the CSS animation. **Is there a way I can have the word perform the animation and then have it disappear from the page?**

I can't show you my current code, as I'm using it in a final project soon. I'll provide an outline of it though:

```
   <style>
   .word:hover{
        /*This makes the words fall to the bottom of the screen.*/
        -webkit-animation-name: fallDown; 
        -webkit-animation-duration: 6s; 
        animation-name: fallDown;
        animation-duration: 6s;
    }

    #1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
    }

    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes fallDown {
        0%   {animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
        100% {top:97%; display: none;}
    }
    /* Standard syntax */
    @keyframes fallDown {
        0%   {animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
        100% {top:97%; display: none;}
    }


    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="word" id="1"> Falling </div>
    </body>
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Not with just plain CSS but along with JavaScript you can - https://jonsuh.com/blog/detect-the-end-of-css-animations-and-transitions-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You need [animationend - Event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend), it is fired when a CSS animation has completed.

```
$('.word').hover( function(){
    $(this).addClass('animated').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function(){ 
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

here is the css

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation: fallDown 6s;
    animation: fallDown 6s;

}
```

DEMO (Use full page mode to see it)

```js
$('.word').hover( function(){
    $(this).addClass('animated').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function(){ 
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes fallDown {
    to {top:97%; display: none;}
}
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes fallDown {
    to {top:97%; display: none;}
}
.word{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
.animated {
    -webkit-animation: fallDown 6s;
    animation: fallDown 6s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="word"> Falling </div>
```